# Prove that the set of vectors are always linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \in V$ be  arbitrary vectors in a real vector space. Show that the vectors $w_1=v_1-v_2,, w_2=v_2-v_3, w_3=v_1-v_3$ are always linearly dependent.

My approach is to use proof by contradiction. I assume that the vectors $w_1,w_2 ,w_3$ are linearly independent, so:
$$a\cdot w_1 +b\cdot w_2+c\cdot w_3 =0\implies a=0, b=0, c=0$$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$

The contrapositive would be:$$a≠0 \lor b≠0 \lor c≠0 \implies a\cdot w_1 +b\cdot w_2+c\cdot w_3 ≠0$$

Without loss of generality I pick $a=b=c=1$, which gives me:
$$v_1-v_2 +v_2-v_3+v_1-v_3=0=w_3+w_3$$
so we found that the vectors are not linearly independent, since the zero vector can be obtained without the the coefficients themselves being 0.

I find this proof way too long than it is supposed to be, given that it is right in the first place. How would one prove it otherwise, perhaps in (far) fewer steps?

Comment: $w_1+w_2=w_3$ is enough.

Comment: @lulu Ahh, when insight saves more time than losing yourself in all the formalism..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with writing long proofs when you are first learning a subject.

Comment: It seems $v_4$ has nothing to do with $w_1,w_2,w_3.$